# OrientDB Studio - Vertex label, display only first N characters

Tags: orientdb

My vertex labels are hashes, so they are very long, I want to display only the first N characters of the label in the Studio Graph view.
Can that be done?

you can see how to change the labels here:
[Showing node labels in OrientDB Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112078/showing-node-labels-in-orientdb-studio)

Answer (score 3):

Not in current version (2.2.2), but we are working to make the graph UI more customizable